# Using Flexible Collision Library (FCL)

Tags: c++11, collision-detection, robotics

I am trying to implement self-Collision checks on a manipulator arm using the *Flexible Collision Library* and its difficult to find examples or tutorials.

The documentation available at for is not verbose enough with examples for integration and I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Where can I find any suitable resources?

Comment: Maybe you can start from reading the code snippets from https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl#interfaces and the related interfaces, which is well documented in the header files.

Comment: Before asking a question, please make sure to check if it is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Asking to recommend an off-site resource such as a tutorial or a library are strictly off topic for Stack Overflow, but you may find suggestions elsewhere on the web.